# on setValue the form controls are updated but the output object is not

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

i have a scenario like on select of dropdown option, on select event is fired. onSelect am updating my form with setValue or patchValue. But the issue is its updating the formControl but not the output object.

```js
this.myForm = this.fb.group({
card : new FormControl('', [])
})

onSelectOption(event){
//event contains each option which is selected
this.myForm.controls['card'].setValue(event);
}

onSubmit(){
console.log(this.myForm.value);// the card is not updated
console.log(this.myForm.getRawValue());// the card is updated
console.log(this.myForm.controls['card'].value);//the card is updated here
console.log(this.myForm.valid) // Invalid
}
```

```html
<select (onSelect)="onSelectOption($event)">
  <option *ngFor="let card of cards">{{card}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: where have you defined onSelectOption?

Comment: You can check now. Thanks

Comment: instead of setting event in setValue, try event.target.value

Comment: @MdJunaidAlam event.target.value is fine, but my issue is while form submit.

Comment: As @Chellappanவ mentioned, could you create a demo on Stackblitz or online sandbox of your choice?